# Replace category with page name in breadcrumb-navxt plugin

Tags: breadcrumb

I am using the "breadcrumb-navxt" plugin and have following issue:

I have a page and some posts in that page. When I go to that page and selects a post to display as single post the breadcrumb shows

> Home>pagename>postname

which is what I need, but when I hover over the link on `'pagename'` it shows `'category/postname'` which should be `'pagename'`.

I found the following piece of code in `class.bcn_breadcrumb.php` file  which might be generating the category of post but don't know what to replace it with;

```
    //Figure out the anchor for current category
    $breadcrumb->set_url(get_term_link($term, $term->taxonomy));
    }
    //Get parents of current category
    if($term->parent)
    {
        $this->term_parents($term->parent, $term->taxonomy);
    }
```

I need to change category/postname to pagename.

Comment: As far as I can see that, that's specific to the plugin, but not to wordpress?

Comment: Change the structure in your Permalink settings. This question relates to a plugin which is off topic as not specific to WordPress.